# Disable multiple selection in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide, multiple-cursor

I was coding something and suddenly android studio started placing cursors on each and every selected line. I dont know if it is a feature that was fired because of some shortcuts that I am not aware of. This is the gif screencast.

[image]

How can I disable this behavior? Is it a feature? If so how to activate and deactivate it? What is it called?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206586055-URGENT-HELP-How-do-I-turn-off-the-multiple-caret-thing) post could be useful. I assume Android Studio has the same shortcuts as IntelliJ.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must have activated **Column Selection Mode**.

Use `Main Menu | Edit | Column Selection Mode` to toggle it ON/OFF.

Check more on different ways how you can work with Multiple Carets: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html#column_selection

Comment: in Edit tab not Editor, but ty :)

Comment: @evals every time you see something that can be edit in a answer or question, you can edit yourself and improve it. Hope you not take it in a bad way. Just remembering you that this is a good option :)

Comment: I didn't know about the edit feature. sorry for that and thank you for the tip @LeonardoSibela

Answer (score 9):

If you are on mac ⌘ (Cmd) + ↑ (Shift) + 8 will disable/enable it by default.